# Passing MyClass defined in header as function argument to other file

Tags: c++, function, header, arguments

I've spent around an hour and couldn't find anything helpful on the Web. The problem is that I've got some files like a.h, b.h, a.cpp, b.cpp and main.cpp. In a.h I've got declared a container with attributes defined by myself. I would like to pass this container as and argument to the function in b.h/b.cpp. What is the way of doing this?

a.h file

```
struct Container{
int size;
int* array
...};
```

b.cpp

```
void someFunction(Container container)
{...}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's called `#include`.

Comment: g++ returns redefinition error. I've included already a.h in main.cpp.

Comment: I edited my answer to cover the redefinition problem you mentioned. You need include guards to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for answering my question. It worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#include "file"` to include the files you need.

[Further reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

For example in `b.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"

void someFunction(Container container);
```

You should also put **include guards** into your header files.
They prevent unwanted multiple inclusion of the same file. If your file is called `a.h`, you would write the following:

`a.h` :

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

// ... your code ...

#endif // A_H
```

Answer (score 3):

In b.h you should put `#include "a.h"` so that the container description is available. After that you can simply declare your functions like you have them in the question. So your files would look like this:

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

struct Container{
int size;
int* array
...};

#endif // A_H
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

void someFunction(Container container);

#endif // B_H
```

b.cpp

```
void someFunction(Container container)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Avoid including a `.h` into another one unless you consequently use *include guards*. Currently if `main.cpp` contains `#include "a.h"; #include "b.h"`, you'll get `struct container already defined` error. And use double quote `"` instead of brackets `<>` for inclusion all local files ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Added include guards to the examples. I don't think that the are completely necessary to illustrate the point here though.

Comment: They were *since you proposed to put `#include "a.h"` in `b.h` instead of `b.cpp`*. And you still forgot to use `""` instead of `<>` ...